# Does the key material of the secret key need to Hex encode? (Java)

Tags: java, secret-key

When I want save my secret key to file, I found snap code below.

Why should we encode the key with hex format before we save it?

What's the difference between those two snap codes below?

**Snap code 1**

```
public static void saveKey(SecretKey key, File file) throws IOException {
    byte[] encoded = key.getEncoded();
    char[] hex = Hex.encodeHex(encoded);
    String data = String.valueOf(hex);
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, data);
}
```

**Snap code 2**

```
public static void saveKey(SecretKey key, File file) throws IOException {
    byte[] encoded = key.getEncoded();
    FileUtils.writeStringToFile(file, new String(encoded));
}
```

Comment: Not all `byte`s make reasonable strings.

Comment: String is not a container for binary data. Repeat after me. String is not a container for binary data.

Comment: String is not a container for binary data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Snap code 1** correctly writes any secret key to a file as a hex-encoded string. It is always reversible.

**Snap code 2** is not good at all. It relies on the bytes backing the `key` being a valid sequence of bytes in the platform's default charset. If it's not, the behaviour is undefined. i.e. the string that is returned may not be reversible back to the original byte sequence.

Comment: Can we use other codec? Or it must be Hex-encoded format?

Comment: Sure you can. If the file must be text then base64 is an option. If there's no requirement for the file to be text then just write out the byte array and do away with the string stuff entirely. I am a little concerned that secret keys are being written to disk apparently without any protection though...

Comment: Thank you @Andy Brown. About the secret key, I will encrypt it with another master key before I save it on disk.